# Tracking data size over network -- iPhone server communication

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4, profiling

I want to log the number of bytes being transferred from my iPhone app to server so that I could put a watch on the bandwidth being eaten up and could take necessary actions.

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you using to communicate with the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Instruments** there is *Network Activity Monitor* that does what you need. You can always correlate your findings with network usage numbers in your Settings.app on actual device. *Settings->General->Usage*

Update: 
Second approach:

1. Make sure you use cellular connection first
2. Reset your data counter.
3. Launch your app and perform operations that interested in
4. Quit your app and see the traffic used in Settings.app

On the picture below is traffic used for my app in 2 minutes. 
[image]

Comment: Can you please guide me how to integrate Network Activity Monitor with Settings.app?

Comment: @Abhinav You can't integrate one with another. You can get the information asked in two different ways. First is by using *Network Activity Monitor* which is a part of Intsrument.app that comes with Xcode, and another one is by using stats your phone shows. Second one will be contaminated with a traffic generated by iOS itself but still useful since it'll show you real empirical data.

Comment: Ok ok... Can you please throw some more light on second option. How to achieve that.